# Recursive solution to finding patterns

Tags: algorithm, recursion, logic

I was solving a problem on recursion which is to count the total number of consecutive 8's in a number. For example:

```
input: 8801 output: 2
input: 801 output: 0
input: 888 output: 3
input: 88088018 output:4
```

I am unable to figure out the logic of passing the information to the next recursive call about whether the previous digit was an 8.

I do not want the code but I need help with the logic. For an iterative solution, I could have used a flag variable, but in recursion how do I do the work which flag variable does in an iterative solution. Also, it is not a part of any assignment. This just came to my mind because I am trying to practice coding using recursion.

Comment: The largest number of consecutive 8s in 88088018 is 2, not 4.

Comment: @j_random_hacker consider the example in a dictionary: `con·sec·u·tive: following continuously. e.g., "five consecutive months of serious decline."` This seems to align more with four consecutive 8s in 88088018. No?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I think that dictionary definition, which I totally agree with, absolutely aligns more with my claim.  The only way that 88088018 contains 4 "consecutive" 8s is if we are not supposed to count 0-digits.

Comment: @j_random_hacker no, total would be two consecutive 8s plus two consecutive 8s.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: I missed the word "total" in the description, and on second thought that makes your interpretation plausible.  I still think it's a very unclear problem description though, since if you talk about a number of consecutive things, it is (I think) universally understood to mean that the *entire collection* appears without gaps.  E.g. if you ask someone whether there are "five consecutive months of serious decline" in a dataset where Jan, Feb, Jun, Jul and Aug had serious decline, and all other months did not, they will say "No".

Comment: @j_random_hacker I would agree with your last example. The concept seems not all together intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

A typical solution to this would be to add a new parameter to your function to pass along the "flag" state. This parameter is usually called an [accumulator](http://www.siddharta.me/2006/04/recursion-part-2-tail-recursion.html). If you're using a language that allows for nested functions, you often want to define an outer function that takes the actual parameters, then an inner, recursive function with an accumulator as a parameter. There's an example in Scheme [here](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~jacobson/scheme/session10.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can scan through your number digit by digit with this function

```
int totalConsecutive8(int digit, boolean last)
```

while boolean last indicate whether the last digit (which mean `digit - 1`) is 8 or not.

For example, in the last example 88088018, starting at digit 0, boolean last is false -> digit 1, as the last digit is 8, so last is true ...

Code in Java

```
public int numberOfConsecutive8(int val){
     String number = "" + val;
     return totalConsecutive8(number, 0, false, false);

}

public int totalConsecutive8(String number, int digit, boolean last, boolean first){
    if(digit == number.length()){
       return 0;
    }
    int result = 0;
    if(number.charAt(digit) == '8'){
       if(last){
          if(first){ 
             result += 2 + totalConsecutive8(number, digit + 1, true, false);
          }else{
             result += 1 + totalConsecutive8(number, digit + 1, true, false);
          }  
       }else{
            result += totalConsecutive8(number, digit + 1, true, true);
       }
    }else{
       result += totalConsecutive8(number, digit + 1, false, false);   
    }
    return result;
}
```

Barmar suggested approach:

```
int totalConsecutive8(int number, boolean last , boolean first){
     if(number == 0){
        return 0;
     }
     int result = 0;
     if(number % 10 == 8){

        if(last){
          if(first){
             result += 2 + totalConsecutive8(number/10, true , false){
          }else{
             result += 1 + totalConsecutive8(number/10, true , false){
          }
        } else{
          result += totalConsecutive8(number/10, true , true){
        } 
     }else{
        result +=   totalConsecutive8(number/10, false , false){
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: The first argument should presumably be `number`, not `digit`, since it's the remaining number after the initial digits have been removed. Otherwise you won't have anything to recurse on.

Comment: @Barmar If you convert the number to string, you can refer to each digit by its index in the string, so you don't need to remove the first digits, plus this can be done with a very large number

Comment: Either way, my point is that in a recursive algorithm, the argument has to be the remaining digits, not a single digit. Each recursive step checks the first digit, then recurses on the remainder.

Comment: @Barmar yes, so in the case 88088018, we slowly gone through from 0 to 7, digit 0 is 8, digit 1 is 8, digit 2 is 0,.. to check whether the current digit is a consecutive 8 or not, we only need to base on the last digit I guess, with a corner case is for the first time we detect a consecutive 8, we need to add 2 into the final result, not just one.

Comment: @Barmar understand your point :), it is a different implementation, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As you are focusing on recursion I'd mention that one of its specifics and benefits that there is no need at all to pass any additional parameter or count calls.

You perform call of your function from inside of its own with modified argument - say the string minus one digit which you check in your function - and then call it again until the string becomes empty.

May be multiple times - nested calls.

**[UPDATE]**
Below is the example in Python, verbose fore more readability.
We call our function with string, current chain of consecutive 8s which is flushed if the 1st char of current string is not '8' (which, and already known total cosecutive 8s

```
def f8_trace(s, chainlen=0, total=0, indent=0):
    print '  '*indent, "invoked with s='%s', chainlen=%d, total=%d" % (s,chainlen, total)
    if len(s) == 0:
        if chainlen>1:
            total += chainlen
        retval = total
    else:
        if s[0] == '8':
            chainlen += 1
        else:
            if chainlen>1:
                total += chainlen
            chainlen = 0
        retval = f8_trace(s[1:],chainlen,total,indent+1)
    print '  '*indent, 'returns %d' % (retval)
    return retval

s = 'abc888d88e8f888'
print f8_trace( s )
```

## Output:

```
 invoked with s='abc888d88e8f888', chainlen=0, total=0
   invoked with s='bc888d88e8f888', chainlen=0, total=0
     invoked with s='c888d88e8f888', chainlen=0, total=0
       invoked with s='888d88e8f888', chainlen=0, total=0
         invoked with s='88d88e8f888', chainlen=1, total=0
           invoked with s='8d88e8f888', chainlen=2, total=0
             invoked with s='d88e8f888', chainlen=3, total=0
               invoked with s='88e8f888', chainlen=0, total=3
                 invoked with s='8e8f888', chainlen=1, total=3
                   invoked with s='e8f888', chainlen=2, total=3
                     invoked with s='8f888', chainlen=0, total=5
                       invoked with s='f888', chainlen=1, total=5
                         invoked with s='888', chainlen=0, total=5
                           invoked with s='88', chainlen=1, total=5
                             invoked with s='8', chainlen=2, total=5
                               invoked with s='', chainlen=3, total=5
                               returns 8
                             returns 8
                           returns 8
                         returns 8
                       returns 8
                     returns 8
                   returns 8
                 returns 8
               returns 8
             returns 8
           returns 8
         returns 8
       returns 8
     returns 8
   returns 8
 returns 8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

here pseudo code for the above problem :-

```
int max = 0;

void cal_eight(char ch[],int i,int count) {

 if(ch[i]=='\0') {

     max = maximum(max,count);
 }

 else if(ch[i]=='8') {

    cal_eight(ch,i+1,count+1);

 }

 else {
    max = maximum(max,count);
    cal_eight(ch,i+1,0);
 }

}

call :- cal_eight(ch,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in Haskell, a language often associated with recursive approaches.

`xxs` stands for the string, `x` and `xs` loosely mean, "first item" and "the rest" (so after we check `x`, we pass `xs`, the rest of the string, to the next function call).

`previous` set as True means the previous digit was an 8. I hope the rest of the code may seem more straight forward and self-explanatory. The guards, `|`, are like imperative "if" clauses (e.g., if previous then ...).

```
f xxs first8 previous count
  | null xxs  = count
  | previous  = if x == 8 
                   then f xs 0 True (count + first8 + 1)
                   else g
  | otherwise = if x == 8 
                   then f xs 1 True count
                   else g
 where x:xs = xxs
       g = f xs 0 False count
```

Output:

```
*Main> f [8,0,1] 0 False 0
0

*Main> f [8,8,8] 0 False 0
3

*Main> f [8,8,0,8,8,0,1,8] 0 False 0
4
```